# Iron deficiency anemia

Tags: physiology, hematology, human-physiology, red-blood-cell

It is said that iron deficiency anemia is characterised by microcytic-hypochromic RBCs. I would like to ask how iron deficiency causes decrease in the volume of RBCs? If the volume is decreasing because of low hemoglobin, then why  does the concentration of hb too decreases causing hypochromic RBCs? **Why don't they decrease in same pace?**

Comment: @anongoodnurse please see the bold text in the question.

Comment: Still think it's a dupe (bolding didn't change anything.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse there question is just about size but I want to know if the size is decreasing since hb has less concentration then why do it's concentration too gets decreases in the new rbcs? Shouldn't the concentration be same since volume is decrased? So why don't they decrease with same pace?